# Clipping GraphicsPath without using Graphics.SetClip()

Tags: c#, graphics, region, clipping, graphicspath

In general, the problem is quite simple.  I need to crop GraphicsPath by rectangle and result of the operation must be another GraphicsPath. 
Graphics.SetClip() does what I need but I can't get cropped GraphicsPath as output
and ideally I want to avoid of using Graphics instance. 
Regions don't work as well because Regions can't be converted back to GraphicsPath.

Any other options?

Comment: Given the highly complex makeup of the constituents of a graphicspath clipping it sounds like a nasty job. I wouldn't want to get into that! Instead try to look into how it is created.. You may want to expand the question and explain what parts make up your path(s9..!